# Blank space occur in the reputation summary in profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-summary

Take a look at my meta [profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186599/azik).

[image: Reputation summary with just one entry]

Why does it occur with just one entry, and without "view more"? Even I have [two more posts with upvotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Tr8.png) today.

Comment: now its show this post with the previous one but, the previous post shows 115 rep, I think the rep tab summary will only deal with max of 120.

Comment: forget the white-space you don't even have the view more link....

Comment: @Arjan, I didn't notice the `view more` button missing :)

Comment: here is another [one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/215468/undo?tab=summary).

Comment: I'm more disappointed that there isn't a properly [hand drawn red circle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/226613) or an ["Eeek!"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83625/226613) in this question.

Comment: There's no "view more" because there are less than four lines. As for why less than four lines that's the bug, it was reported before already.